# Wait for processing of whole configuration using @DependsOn annotations

Tags: java, spring-boot

I found a quite counterintuitive example of behavior of `@DependsOn` annotations. I'm using Spring Boot 3.2.0. In the following toy example, I would expect that `ConditionalConfig` is matched only when `FalseConfig` is also matched, but actually `ConditionalConfig` is always matched. It seems to me that my expectation should be exactly the intended behavior of `@DependsOn` (obviously!): wait for the initialization of a `OtherBean`, then, if necessary, initialize a `MyBean`. What is wrong with my understanding? Adding explicit component scanning did not solve the issue.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    public static class MyBean {}

    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class OtherBean { Object o; }

    @Configuration
    @DependsOn("otherBean")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyBean.class)
    public static class ConditionalConfig {

        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean() {
            return new MyBean();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "org.example.condition", havingValue = "false")
    public static class FalseConfig {

        @Bean
        public OtherBean otherBean() {
            return new OtherBean(null);
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "org.example.condition", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public static class TrueConfig {

        @Bean
        public OtherBean otherBean(MyBean myBean) {
            return new OtherBean(myBean);
        }

        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean() {
            return new MyBean();
        }

    }

}
```